# Need Help on Java 8 stream logic

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have an array list containing multiple strings. I need to replace one of the item in that list with updated value based on some condition and retain other strings. I need help in doing Java 8's way.

**Code Sample:**

```
String newPONumber = "Orig PO#: 22222222222222456";
List<String> existingMessages = Arrays.asList("Orig PO#: 2222222222222222    ", "this is a sample string     ");
List<String> updatedMessages =  new ArrayList<>();
System.out.println("Existing Messages");
existingMessages.stream().forEach(System.out::println);


//Java 8's way that I tried but losing the existing messages since filter is used
updatedMessages = existingMessages.stream()
        .filter(message -> message != null)
        .map(String :: trim)
        .map(String:: toUpperCase)
        .filter(message -> message.startsWith("ORIG"))
        .map(message -> newPONumber)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println("New Messages");
updatedMessages.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output should contain all the message plus the updated Orig PO# string

```
//"Orig PO#: 2222222222222456", "this is a sample string"
```

Traditional for loop way

```
for(String message : existingMessages) {
    message = message.trim();
    if(message.startsWith("ORIG")) {
        message = newPONumber;
    }
    updatedMessages.add(message);                   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do that would be

```
List<String> updatedMessages = existingMessages.stream()
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .map(String::trim)
        .map(message -> message.toUpperCase().startsWith("ORIG") ? newPONumber : message)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

*Notice*: The `toUpperCase` is only applicable within the condition and is not on the resultant string as in your traditional `for` loop solution.

Comment: I prefer `message.regionMatches(true, 0, "ORIG", 0, 4)` over `message.toUpperCase().startsWith("ORIG")`, to avoid converting the entire string to uppercase, just to match four characters.

Comment: @Holger thanks for sharing the information, I just haven't used that API ever.
How often do you make me feel how little do I know about Java APIs!

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is `replaceAll`:

```
existingMessages.replaceAll(s -> s == null ? s : s.trim().toUpperCase().startsWith("ORIG") ? newPONumber : s.trim());
```

or if you don't want to modify `existingMessages`:

```
List<String> updatedMessages = new ArrayList<>(existingMessages);
updatedMessages.replaceAll(s -> s == null ? s : s.trim().toUpperCase().startsWith("ORIG") ? newPONumber : s.trim());
```

Comment: @Suresh this is "java-8" as `replaceAll` wasn't available before then. seems like you're looking for a "stream" solution in which case @nullpointers answer is what you're after.

Comment: you are right. I am more inclined towards stream solution. Thanks for the help.

Comment: There is a contradiction in the OP’s way of dealing with `null`. The Op’s stream code would remove `null` elements, whereas the shown loop equivalent doesn’t expect `null` at all. Your version of checking for `null` but keeping them matches neither. My preferred solution would be to follow the example of the loop reference code and not checking for `null` at all. By the way, you could avoid calling `trim` twice by using `replaceAll(s -> (s = s.trim()).toUpperCase().startsWith("ORIG")? newPONumber: s)`, but not everyone likes such constructs…

Comment: @Holger in which case one can use removeIf before replaceAll to filter the null elements out then there’s no need to check for nullity in the following line. Might not be the best approach but should suffice.

Comment: Yes, if you want to handle `null` like in the first variant, you can do a `existingMessages.removeIf(Objects::isNull)` first, however, I’d rather not do this step but define absence of `null` as a requirement.